# Characterization of $C^{k,\alpha}$ (functions with Hölder continuous derivatives) through Taylor estimates

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, holder-spaces, stochastic-pde

For $k \in \Bbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\dots\}$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, let us define
$$
C^{k,\alpha} := \{ f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} \,:\, f \in C^k \text{ with } f, f', \dots, f^{(k)} \text{ bounded and } [f^{(k)}]_{C^\alpha} < \infty \},
$$
where
$$
[g]_{C^\alpha} := \sup_{x,y \in \Bbb{R}, x \neq y} \frac{|g(x)-g(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} \, .
$$

It is not hard to see by using Taylor's formula for $f \in C^{k,\alpha}$ that for each $x \in \Bbb{R}$, there is a polynomial $P_x$ of degree $k$ (namely, the Taylor polynomial of $f$) satisfying
$$
|f(x+h) - P_x (h)| \leq C \cdot |h|^{k+\alpha} \qquad \forall h \in \Bbb{R} \text{ with } |h| \leq 1, \tag{$\circledast$}
$$
with a constant $C$ independent of $x,h$ (but depending on $f$).

> It is claimed in Exercise 13.31 of [certain notes by Martin Hairer](http://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf) that also the converse holds, i.e., if $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ and if there is a constant $C>0$, such that for each $x$, there is a polynomial $P_x$ of degree at most $k$ such that $(\circledast)$ holds, then $f \in C^{k,\alpha}$.

I would like to know a solution to this exercise, and even the case $k=1$ would be interesting to me.

To simplify the question a bit, let us assume that we already know $f$ to be $k$-times differentiable, with $f,f', \dots, f^{(k)}$ being bounded (I think this boundedness does not actually follow "automatically"), so we only need to establish $\alpha$-Hölder continuity of $f^{(k)}$.

After the fold, I discuss some of my ideas towards this problem. It might be better, however, to at first not read these ideas, since given that this is an exercise, they seem overly complicated (they refer to Campanato spaces, which are probably not known to everyone doing the exercise). Thus it might be better to start afresh instead of getting spoiled by my stupid thoughts :)

---

My thoughts only apply to the case $k=1$. Here, one can more or less easily show that necessarily $P_x (h) = f(x) + f'(x) h$.
Then we get
\begin{align*}
& |f(x+h) - f(x-h) - 2h \cdot f'(x)| \\
& = |f(x+h) - f(x) - f'(x) h - (f(x-h) - f(x) - f'(x) \cdot (-h))| \\
& \leq 2C |h|^{1+\alpha}
\end{align*}
for $|h| \leq 1$. But using the fundamental theorem of calculus to write $f(x+h) - f(x-h) = \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f'(s) ds$, and writing $g = f'$, we thus get
$$
\left|
- \int_{x-h}^{x+h} g(s) - g(x) ds
\right|
\leq 2C \cdot |h|^{1+\alpha}. \tag{$\dagger$}
$$
Now, it is known (see Lemma 0.0.15 in [Some notes on Campanato spaces](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f12/MorreyCampanato.pdf)) that the norm
$$
\| g \|_\ast = \|g\|_{L^1} + \sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}, 0 < h \leq C} \,\, \inf_{c \in \Bbb{R}} \,\, h^{-(1 + \alpha)} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} |g(t) - c| \, dt
$$
is an equivalent norm for the Campanato space $L^{1,1+\alpha}_C (\Bbb{R})$. Strictly speaking, I am cheating a bit here, since $\Bbb{R}$ is not a bounded domain.

Thus, if in $(\dagger)$ above, we would have the absolute value **inside** the integral instead of outside, we would get a Campanato condition on the function $g = f'$. But it is known (see Wikipedia, or Theorem 0.0.22 of the notes I linked above) that $L^{1, 1+\alpha}_C = C^{0,\alpha}$ is the space of $\alpha$-Hölder continuous functions.

Thus, my hope is (I am currently investigating this) that one can adapt the arguments from the lecture notes above to also work in the case where the absolute value is outside of the integral.

> As I said above, I don't think that this is the right solution, since it seems overly complicated :) I would be happy about any thoughts!

Comment: If I understood well you would like to know why the existence of polynomial implies the Holder regularity?

Comment: @GuyFsone: Yes, indeed. I want to know why/if existence of the polynomials implies $\alpha$-Hölder regularity of the $k$-th derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$
|f(x+h)-P_{x}(h)|\leq c|h|^{k+\alpha}%
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $h$ with $|h|\leq1$. Write
$$
P_{x}(h)=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}a_{n}(x)h^{n}.
$$
Taking $h=0$ you get $f(x)=a_{0}(x)$ so
$$
\left\vert f(x+h)-f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}a_{n}(x)h^{n}\right\vert \leq
c|h|^{k+\alpha}.
$$
Next, by the triangle inequality
\begin{align*}
\left\vert f(x+h)-f(x)-a_{1}(x)h\right\vert  & \leq\left\vert f(x+h)-f(x)-\sum
_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}a_{n}(x)h^{n}\right\vert +\sum_{n=2}^{k}|a_{n}%
(x)||h|^{n}\\
& \leq c|h|^{k+\alpha}+\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}|a_{n}(x)||h|^{n}%
\end{align*}
and so%
$$
\left\vert \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-a_{1}(x)h}{h}\right\vert \leq c|h|^{k-1+\alpha
}+\sum_{n=2}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}|a_{n}(x)||h|^{n-1}\rightarrow0
$$
as $h\rightarrow0$, which shows that $f$ is differentiable with $f^{\prime
}(x)=a_{1}(x)$.

**%%%%%This part feels wrong but I cannot find the mistake%%%%%%%%%%%%**
Hence, for $k=1$,
$$
\left\vert f(x+h)-f(x)-f^{\prime}(x)h\right\vert \leq c|h|^{1+\alpha}.
$$

In turn, replacing $x$ with $x-h$ we get
$$
\left\vert f(x)-f(x-h)-f^{\prime}(x-h)h\right\vert \leq c|h|^{1+\alpha}%
$$
while replacing $h$ with $-h$ gives
$$
\left\vert f(x-h)-f(x)+f^{\prime}(x)h\right\vert \leq c|h|^{1+\alpha}.
$$
Now
\begin{align*}
|f^{\prime}(x)-f^{\prime}(x-h)|  & \leq\left\vert \frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}
{h}+f^{\prime}(x)\right\vert +\left\vert -\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}-f^{\prime
}(x-h)\right\vert \\
& =\left\vert \frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}+f^{\prime}(x)\right\vert +\left\vert
\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}-f^{\prime}(x-h)\right\vert \\
& \leq2c|h|^{\alpha}.
\end{align*}

This proves that $f^{\prime}$ is Holder's continuous.

**%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%End funny part %%%%%%%%%%%%**

For $k\geq2$ we first prove that all the functions $a_{n}$ are bounded in
$[a,b]$. We will use the following fact about polynomials. Given
$k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials
$P:[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of degree less than or equal to $k$. Given
$P\in V$, let $\Vert P\Vert:=\max\{|a_{0}|,\ldots,|a_{k}|\}$, where
$P(t)=a_{0}+\cdots+a_{k}t^{k}$, $t\in\lbrack-1,1]$. Then $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is
a norm in $V$.

Since the vector space $V$ has finite dimension $k$, all norms are equivalent.
In particular,%
$$
c_{1}\Vert P\Vert_{L^{\infty}([-1,1])}\leq\Vert P\Vert\leq c_{2}\Vert
P\Vert_{L^{\infty}([-1,1])}%
$$
for all $P\in V$ and for some constants $c_{1}>0$ and $c_{2}>0$.

Now let $P\in V$ be such that $\Vert P\Vert_{L^{\infty}([-1,1])}\leq L$. Then
by the previous inequality,%
$$
\Vert P\Vert:=\max\{|a_{0}|,\ldots,|a_{k}|\}\leq c_{2}\Vert P\Vert_{L^{\infty
}([-1,1])}\leq c_{2}L,
$$
which implies that $|a_{n}|\leq c_{2}L$ for all $n=1, \ldots, k$.

Since $f$ is continuous, there exists
$$
M=\max_{[a-1,b+1]}|f(x)|<\infty
$$
and so for $-1\leq h\leq1$ we have
\begin{align*}
\left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}a_{n}(x)h^{n}\right\vert  &
\leq\left\vert f(x+h)-f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}a_{n}(x)h^{n}\right\vert
+\left\vert f(x+h)-f(x)\right\vert \\
& \leq c|h|^{k+\alpha}+2M\leq c+2M.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$
\left\vert \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}a_{n}(x)h^{n}\right\vert \leq c+2M
$$
for all $h\in\lbrack-1,1]$. It follows from the property about polynomials
above that there exists a constant $C=C(a,b,M,c)>0$ such that%
$$
|a_{n}(x)|\leq C
$$
for all $x\in\lbrack a,b]$ and all $n=1,\ldots,k$.

We can now apply Theorem 3 in [Oliver's paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1954-076-03/S0002-9947-1954-0062207-1/S0002-9947-1954-0062207-1.pdf) to conclude that $a_{n}%
(x)=f^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I will have a detailed look at it this evening.

Comment: You can try using the Lagrange reminder of the Taylor series.

Comment: Maybe there is a wrong minus sign in the "funny" part when you add and subtract the increment. Apart from this it seems correct: in fact you see that you do not get continuity of the derivatives if $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}.$ This corresponds to the difference between Holder and Zygmund spaces.

Comment: I cannot see the sign mistake. Where is it exactly? Thanks!

Comment: @Gio67: I am sorry that it took me so long to come back to your answer. I think that everything is correct. Also the reference to the paper by Oliver is interesting, since it shows that the notion in question has a name. If I understand correctly, what you show implies that 1) if $k=1$, then $f \in C^{k,\alpha}$, as desired. 2) if $k > 1$, then $f$ is $k$-times differentiable, and the polynomial $P_x$ is in fact the Taylor polynomial of $f$.

Comment: Do these claims also show $f \in C^{k,\alpha}$ for $k > 1$? At least I do not easily see at the moment that they do... Note: Even if not, I will award the bounty to you if no other answer comes up. Thank you :)

Comment: correct. I have not proved that the higher order derivatives are Holder

Comment: @PhoemueX, would you all mind to take a look of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2718164/lifchitz-functions-form-a-banach-space-and-analyzing-its-dual)? I wish to find a dense subset of $\text{Lip}$ but I failed.

Comment: Can your proof be extended to general $\mathbb{R}^n$? The part ('funny part') of dividing the equalities by $h$ might need more illustrations in  $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $n \geq 2$.

Comment: Yes, I think so. One could work with partial derivatives. I cannot see a problem, although I would need to sit down and check.

Comment: @Gio67 The subtle difference is that (by copying your method to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n \geq 2$), after doing triangle inequality, one may end up with $\vert (\nabla f^{T}(x)-\nabla f^{T}(x-hd)) \cdot hd\vert \leq 2c \vert h \vert^{1+\alpha}$, where $d$ is a unit vector of any direction. Then $\vert (\nabla f^{T}(x)-\nabla f^{T}(x-hd))\cdot d\vert \leq 2c \vert h \vert^{\alpha}$. With this we can show Holder continuity of partial derivatives along only one direction (taking $d = e_i$). But I can't show that's true for other directions. Would you mind illustrating this a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: There is a book called "Manifolds, Tensor Analysis, and Applications" by Ralph Abraham , Jerrold E. Marsden , Tudor Ratiu. On Page 99 they have a supplement called "The converse to Taylor's theorem". The proof is not easy though.